# Get data from Controller in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, web

I  want to send my data from controller to xedit.blade.php, but I get the same error:

```
 Undefined variable: users
```

in controller:

```
public function index3()
    {
        $users=User::all();

    return view('xedit')->with('users' => $users);

    }
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('admin/edit', function () {
    return view('xedit');
})->name('edit');

 Route::get('edit','Admin\UsersController@index3');
```

and I want to use $users in blade.Maybe there is a Route problem?

Comment: Try this: `return view('xedit')->with(['users' => $users]);`

Comment: @OlegNurutdinov I get the same error

Comment: it seems you get the error when accessing `admin/edit` url but not in just `edit` as users variable is not defined and passed from `admin/edit` url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use this code.

```
Route::get('/admin/edit','AdminController@index3')->name('edit');
```

> It calls the AdminController's index3() and the function returns the view.

```
public function index3()
{
    $users=User::all();
    return view('xedit')->with('users' => $users);
}
```

> The below code won't call the index3() in AdminController but returns
>    the view directly with empty data.

```
Route::get('admin/edit', function () {
    return view('xedit');
})->name('edit');
```

Comment: For the explained case, we should not use the last code.

Comment: Also, if we need not to call Controller function, then we can use the last code to call the view directly.

Comment: Sure. Try and comment if any further queries. @ThiTle

Comment: @ThiTle Was it helpful? If yes, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change

```
Route::get('edit','Admin\UsersController@index3')->name('edit');
```

Comment: I resolved it by putting   $users=User::all(); directly in route file.What do you think,is it correct? no security issues?

Comment: I never use any extract data by using `route`.  I always do in my controller @ThiTle

Answer (score 0):

maybe this route

```
Route::get('admin/edit', function () {
return view('xedit');
})->name('edit');
```

This route doesn't contain $users, maybe this is why it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the same view xedit for both of your routes admin/edit & /edit .
So, when you visit admin/edit `$users` variable in the xedit view file getting no value which means it's undefined. Try to check if `$users` variable is defined before using that.